# Using Linq to get date of last order for all customers

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following two POCO's

```
public class Customers
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Orders
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming my Data Service returns a List<Customers> and List<Orders>, how would I use Linq to Get the Date of the last order for each customer?

I want to return Customer.Id, Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName, Order.Id, Order.Date and Order.Product (as Json from a controller action), so would I need to also create a new POCO to hold results? something like the following:

```
public class CustomerOrders
{
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Guid OrderId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use `GROUP BY` and `JOIN` like this:

```
var customerOrders =
    (from c in customers
     join o in (from o1 in orders
                group o1 by o1.CustomerId into og
                select new { CustomerId = og.Key, Latest = og.Max(d => d.Date) })
     on c.Id equals o.CustomerId
     join o2 in orders
     on new {CustmerId = o.CustomerId, Date = o.Latest } 
     equals new { CustmerId = o2.CustomerId, Date = o2.Date }

     select new CustomerOrders
     {
         CustomerId = c.Id,
         FirstName = c.FirstName,
         LastName = c.LastName,
         OrderId = o2.Id,
         Date = o.Latest,
         Product = o2.Product
     });
```

If you want the results of customers without any order, condier using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with using `DefaultIfEmpty` like this:

```
var customerOrders =
    (from c in customers
     join o in (from o1 in orders
                group o1 by o1.CustomerId into og
                select new { CustomerId = og.Key, Latest = og.Max(d => d.Date) })
     on c.Id equals o.CustomerId into co
     from o in co.DefaultIfEmpty()  // LEFT OUTER JOIN 1
     join o2 in orders
     on new { CustmerId = (o == null)? Guid.Empty : o.CustomerId, Date = (o == null)? DateTime.MinValue : o.Latest }
     equals new { CustmerId = o2.CustomerId, Date = o2.Date } into oo
     from o2 in oo.DefaultIfEmpty()  // LEFT OUTER JOIN 2

     select new CustomerOrders
     {
         CustomerId = c.Id,
         FirstName = c.FirstName,
         LastName = c.LastName,
         OrderId = (o2 == null)? Guid.Empty : o2.Id,
         Date = (o == null)? DateTime.MinValue : o.Latest,
         Product = (o == null)? null : o2.Product
     });
```

Please note `LEFT OUTER JOIN` could be joining with null value so you have to add null checks in the linq query.

Comment: You mentioned LEFT OUTER JOIN and using DefaultIfEmpty. Could you please indicate which join in particular and where I would use DefaultIfEmpty? Thanks

Comment: Hi @user3583 I've update my answer for `LEFT OUTER JOIN` case.